# When should we use linked lists and not arrays, or vice versa?

Tags: c, arrays, vector, linked-list

I got these structure declarations from one of my professor's code, I actually want to know why we should use linked list instead of arrays. I don't know if it is a dumb question, I'm just curios about what the SO community think about this.

```
typedef struct Booking
{
  char restaurant[32];
  char customer[32];
  int  seats;
  int  period; // DAY o NIGHT
} TBooking;

typedef struct NodeBooking
{
  TBooking            booking;
  struct NodeBooking* next;
} TNodeBooking;

typedef TNodeBooking* PNodeBooking;

typedef struct BookingQueue
{
  PNodeBooking first;
  PNodeBooking last;
} TBookingQueue;

typedef struct Restaurant
{
  char              restaurant[32];
  int               n_booking_lunch;
  int               n_booking_dinner;
  TBookingsQueue bookings;
} TRestaurant;

typedef struct NodeRestaurant
{
  TRestaurant            restaurant;
  struct NodeRestaurant* next;
} TNodeRestaurant;

 typedef TNodeRestaurant* PNodeRestaurant;
```

Comment: What do you mean by structure arrays?

Comment: I assume your teacher wants to teach you how to use a linked list? Otherwise, I can't read his mind... You'd almost never use a linked list in practice.

Comment: Well why do we? I rarely use them. Often, it's just because from all "dynamic list" approaches, they're the easiest to implement.

Comment: But for real life code, the only use is when you don't need indexed access, but have a lot of insertions and deletions ... otherwise, there are better container types.

Comment: Linked lists are good stepping stones to more useful pointer-based data structures such as trees. If you can't handle the mechanics of e.g. linked-list traversals then you will probably be lost with tree traversals.

Comment: The main use of linked lists today is in learning how pointers work. They were more generally useful a couple of decades ago, when memory latency wasn't a major performance factor.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Arrays are generally good on the condition that you will not modify the array often (i.e. removals and insertions), and if you need indexed access. Then again, as mentioned in the comments, due to cache locality (and no pointer indirection) arrays will perform better when reading them due to their sequential layout in memory, while linked lists are fragmented in memory and come with a pointer indirection per node. With that in mind, every data structure has their pros and cons in terms of complexity and use cases.

As for some of the drawbacks of arrays, let's assume you have the following array:

```
struct user_s *user_list[] = { &user1, &user2, &user3, &user4 };
```

And imagine that this list contains a lot more many elements.

1. What happens if you want to remove `&user2`? You would have to move everything after the removed element to fill back the removed space, which means copying at worst `N-1` elements in memory.
2. What happens if we run out of the initial reserved size of the array? You'd have to `realloc` more space in memory, and move everything to the newly allocated memory space (that's how `realloc` works). This is also quite expensive.

Although, depending on the kind of elements, using an array or a linked list may be more optimal, and either can be optimized for the use case.

You don't have some of these problems when you have a linked list like the following:

```
struct user_s {
  char *name;

  struct user_s *next;
}
```

Now you can add new elements at the end without reallocating the whole array when the capacity is full:

```
struct user_s *user_add(struct user_s *tail, struct user_s *user)
{
    assert(tail != NULL);
    assert(user != NULL);

    tail->next = user;

    return tail->next;
}
```

This helps with the `2.`nd problem of arrays. You can indefinitely append at the end of a list's tail without hitting the *array capacity*, that requires reallocating more buffer for it. But this reallocation can be optimized by buffering memory space in advance.

The `1.`st problem of removing elements from the middle is even easier:

```
void user_remove(struct user_s *head, struct user_s *user)
{
    struct user_s *it, *prev;

    assert(head != NULL);
    assert(user != NULL);

    for (prev = head, it = head->next; it != NULL; prev = it, it = it->next) {
        if (it == user) {
            prev->next = it->next;
            free(it);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can remove an element from the middle of a list, and bind the previous and next one to each other.

Whereas in an array, in order to remove an element, you would have to create a new array, copy the elements until the element you want removed, and copy the elements after it to the newly allocated array, and return that. This is a very expensive operation if you have to remove elements very often. See https://ideone.com/bOSvpg

In your example, another reason for having a `*next` in the structs is that you almost always need a pointer when implementing the plethora of other data structures that involve such as trees.

Comment: "Measure before you optimize" also means "don't assume performance characteristics without running the code". As it turns out the arrays **still outperform** linked lists due to how the memory works. If you don't my word for it - see this talk from Bjarne himself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo&t=13s

Comment: I updated the answer. It entirely depends on the use case, and in most cases arrays will be good to go. But if you have to remove elements very often, it will most likely be very slow to use arrays. I measured at least the removal operation for a single element from the beginning of the list and array: https://ideone.com/bOSvpg

Answer (score -3):

It has many feature to use linked list, some of it listed below:

- iterate over the structures in list
- use benefit of linked list feature like circular or etc.
- Escape from array index bounding error
- reference pass argument to method, big data could referenced by one pointer
- use search algorithm
- insert and delete some node in list

and so on.

of course you could do all above things with array but linked list is better way in structured application.

Comment: None of that made any sense.

Comment: why you say that? @melpomene

Comment: I guess because indeed, none of that made sense :o

Comment: None of these (except possibly "insert and delete") is an advantage over arrays. And some of them are wrong (e.g. linked lists aren't thread-safe).

Comment: Yeh you're right guy @interjay